# validate model on change of texbox event

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, razor-2

I have a model class

```
public class ActorPhoneModel
    {
        public int PhoneTypeTd { get; set; }

        public string PhoneType { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessage),
            ErrorMessageResourceName = "phone_number_you_entered_must_be_at_least_five_characters", ErrorMessage = "", MinimumLength = 5)]

        [RegularExpression(@"/^[ 0-9()+-]*$/", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorMessage),
            ErrorMessageResourceName = "phone_number_is_invalid", ErrorMessage = "")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

And on View

```
@foreach (var phone in Model.Phones)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@phone .PhoneType</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => phone .PhoneNumber, new
                       {
                           @class = "phoneNumber form-control",
                           data_phoneType = @phone .PhoneTypeTd,
                           data_actorId = Model.ActorId,
                           maxlength = "30"
                       })

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

I am using ajax post to save changed phone number.
And on text changed event of textbox I want to validate a model

```
        $(".phoneNumber").change(function () {
            var phoneType = $(this).attr("data-phoneType");
            var actorId = $(this).attr("data-actorId");
            var phoneNumber = $(this).val();

            if (//validate model) {

                //code to save phone number of that phoneType
            }
        });
```

How I can validate that model in jquery.. I have tried method form.valid() but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to validate by jQuery only, 
since on change of text there is no server side call.
And you need to validate only one field you can go with RegularExpression with jQuery.
Would be much simpler.
Hope this helps.